# Select Atleast one and at least two in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables
`student(ssn,name,major)`
`transcript(ssn,grade)`
what is the query to return

received grade A in at least one course and major CS

received grade A in at least two courses and major CS.

For one course I have tried the below query but I'm not getting the result as expected

`Select * from student s inner join transcript t on s.ssn = t.ssn where s.major = 'cs' and t.grade = 'A'`

help appreciated thank you.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me for answering the first question.

Comment: Query for the second question?

Comment: Which one of your tables/columns indicates the course? Your table structures don’t seem to make a lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

The following nested query might help for your second question

```
SELECT
  s.ssn,
  s.name,
  s.major
FROM student s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    ssn,
    COUNT(grade) as number_of_A_grades
  FROM transcript
  WHERE grade = 'A'
  GROUP BY ssn
) A_grades_count
ON A_grades_count.ssn = s.ssn

WHERE A_grades_count.number_of_A_grades >= 2
```

Comment: Is this possible without using group by

Comment: the solution you gave is perfect but is it possible to write the same query without aggregation operators(sum, count etc) , group by, having

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER()` to avoid aggregate functions to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
  a.ssn, 
  a.name, 
  a.major
FROM (SELECT 
        s.ssn, 
        s.name, 
        s.major,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.ssn ORDER BY s.ssn ASC) AS rn
      FROM student s
      INNER JOIN transcript t ON s.ssn = t.ssn 
      WHERE t.grade = 'A' AND s.major = 'cs') a
WHERE a.rn >= 2
ORDER BY a.ssn ASC
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JOu0Bl92?hide=524272).

Comment: Is there any way we can do it without using GROUP BY/HAVING?

Comment: Possibly*, what do you expect the output to look like exactly?

Comment: The same as the query you have written first

Comment: the first query is not possible without a `GROUP BY` clause, you're trying to aggregate students by grade correct? You'll need an aggregate function like `COUNT` to achieve this which requires a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: this worked for atleast one course CS                   `Select DISTINCT(s.ssn),s.name,s.major from student s inner join transcript t on s.ssn = t.ssn where s.major = 'cs' and t.grade = 'A'`

Comment: Simply add major to the `GROUP BY` clause and remove CS from the `WHERE` clause (I've updated my answer to reflect this).

Comment: If the answers here do not suffice, you should add sample data and your expected output to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248866/discussion-between-griv-and-vamsi-shankar).